# Getting the scatterplot images transformed in an animated gif

Tags: r, animation, ggplot2, gif

I had this idea of creating an animation gif from my scatter plot, and thought if it was possible in the first place.

I have roughly 1000 - 2000 points in a scatter plot, and thought if I could make R generate 1 plot for the first point, 1 plot for the first + second point, 1 plot for the first + second + third and so on, in this way I could get an animation gif of my plot being created and making my presentation more fun and interesting.

There is a way of make the saving png in script?

Could Anyone a least say if it is possible to make this in the first place?

here is my code

```
volcano_plot_mix <- ggplot(data=resultado_table3, aes(x=log2FoldChange, y=-    log10(padj))) +
  geom_point(data=data_shape, size=2, shape=6) +
  geom_point(data=resultado_table3[resultado_table3$threshold==TRUE, ], size=2, colour="#CC0000") +
  geom_point(data=resultado_table3[resultado_table3$threshold2==TRUE, ], size=2, colour="#000099")+
  #scale_colour_manual(name="Legenda",values=legend) +
  xlab("\n log2 fold change") +
  ylab("-log10 p-value adjusted \n") +
  ggtitle("Controle Vs Mistura")+
  scale_x_continuous(limit=c(-6,3), breaks=c(-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limit=c(0,50)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold", size=16, colour="white"),
        axis.title.x = element_text(face="bold", size=16, colour="white"),
        axis.text = element_text(size=12),
        legend.title =element_blank() ,
        legend.text = element_text(size = 12))
  volcano_plot_mix
```

and a piece of my data.frame:

```
row.names   baseMean    log2FoldChange  lfcSE   stat    pvalue  padj    threshold   threshold2
 1  ENSMUSG00000000001  271.556874  -0.2586453163   0.1932363   -1.33849262    1.807359e-01 3.245108e-01    FALSE   FALSE
2   ENSMUSG00000000028  14.425989   -0.7678419135   0.4871996   -1.57603155  1.150185e-01   2.306094e-01    FALSE   FALSE 
3   ENSMUSG00000000031  243.168564  2.8036752381    0.1859020   15.08146607 2.144536e-51    4.498238e-49    TRUE    FALSE
4   ENSMUSG00000000049  5.494035    -0.4191875260   0.6160034   -0.68049552 4.961908e-01    6.568972e-01    FALSE   FALSE
5   ENSMUSG00000000056  507.039921  0.6190059663    0.1371111   4.51463200  6.342681e-06    4.937424e-05    FALSE   FALSE
6   ENSMUSG00000000058  598.257239  1.2975264408    0.1510505   8.59001843  8.695538e-18    3.268956e-16    TRUE    FALSE
7   ENSMUSG00000000078  542.650626  -0.8415712222   0.1891324   -4.44964026   8.601424e-06  6.552488e-05    FALSE   FALSE
8   ENSMUSG00000000085  103.272511  -0.2538031364   0.2236255   -1.13494746 2.563973e-01    4.196936e-01    FALSE   FALSE
9   ENSMUSG00000000088  2289.066560 0.8291929325    0.1194602   6.94116312  3.888847e-12    7.960698e-11    FALSE   FALSE
10  ENSMUSG00000000093  19.973601   -0.4603336297   0.4165947   -1.10499166 2.691632e-01    4.349332e-01    FALSE   FALSE
11  ENSMUSG00000000120  10.267475   -1.4756032832   0.5527286   -2.66967051 7.592571e-03    2.555670e-02    FALSE   TRUE
12  ENSMUSG00000000126  26.757132   0.7317334670    0.3630208   2.01567904  4.383355e-02    1.086051e-01    FALSE   FALSE
```

Comment: Have you tried the animation package? http://yihui.name/animation/

Comment: Never heard. I will check. Thank you.

Comment: I was able to make 100 scatterplot but all identical. I suppose I must write a loop that adds + 1 point in my ggplot and use animation package to do all once?

Comment: Because you are using ggplot in a loop you probably have to do `print(volcano_plot_mix)` because ggplot only actually does the plot when it prints its objects. If still stuck edit your Q to show what you've tried.

Comment: If your data has a row number, `r`, say, then plot all the points but set the `alpha` aesthetic in your ggplot to be `aes([...],alpha=r<=i)` so that only the first `i` point are visible, the rest are transparent...

Comment: Well, actually was very simple to solve: 
Here is what I made:
     `seq1 <- seq(1:3)`
      `for (n in seq1) {`
`#here I used the data with [1:n]`
`geom_point(data=resultado_table3[1:n, ],size=2, colour="#000000") +`
etc......
`print(volcano_plot_mix)`
`}`